# kmeans through time retain consistent cluster ID

Tags: r, dplyr, k-means

There are times when we would like to know how the clustering of points might change through time. For example, say you have cities with demographic attributes by decade and you are interested in what cities are the "most similar" based on their attributes for each decade. Here is a toy dataset that illustrates the point:

```
set.seed(1)
centers <- data.frame(cluster=factor(1:3), 
                      size=c(100, 150, 50), 
                      x1=c(5, 0, -3), 
                      x2=c(-1, 1, -2))

year1 <- centers %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  do(data.frame(x1=rnorm(.$size[1], .$x1[1]),
                x2=rnorm(.$size[1], .$x2[1]),
                year="year 1",
                stringsAsFactors = F)) %>%
  data.frame()

year2 <- centers %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  do(data.frame(x1=rnorm(.$size[1], .$x1[1]),
                x2=rnorm(.$size[1], .$x2[1]),
                year="year 2",
                stringsAsFactors = F)) %>%
  data.frame()


points <- rbind(year1,year2)
```

We can calculate kmeans per year using something like below:

```
kclusters <- points %>%
  select(-cluster) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  do(data.frame(., kclust = kmeans(as.matrix(.[,-3]),centers=3)$cluster)) %>%
  mutate(kclust = as.character(kclust))
```

And here is the resulting plot:

```
ggplot(kclusters) + 
  geom_point(aes(x1,x2,color=kclust)) + 
  facet_wrap(~year) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_viridis_d()
```

[image]

The code works as expected but notice that the cluster IDs have changed. It doesn't make much difference here because I am plotting the clusters using the original x1 and x2, but my real example is making a map and the points are plotted in space using coordinates and colored according to clusters (i.e., the location of the point never changes). Imagine this same plot for several years--it becomes hard to track the changing cluster membership of individual points each year. Is there a way to keep the IDs consistent?

Comment: The function reference mentions that the `centers` argument specifies  either the number of clusters, say k, or a set of initial (distinct) cluster centres. If you used this initial set, i think you could make the IDs consistent.